# How to make spinner editable

Tags: android, spinner

How do I make the user edit the spinner contents?

Such as, I want to give the user the ability to rename the contents of the spinner.

Comment: Did you do at least **some** research?

Comment: Yes, I did. but i am new to java and Android. so your advise please, i already completed my program but i just want to make the user able to edit the text in the spinner

Comment: @user2876982 Check this  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html.

Comment: @Aniruddha i want the user to be able to edit the text in the spinner and not to use auto complete text. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved after adding a list of `String`s.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                           this,
                           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                           list);

sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
```

Then, it's as easy as adding and removing items to/from the list itself.

Comment: How this answer is related to the question and how come it considered as accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Okay create a CustomSpinnerAdapter class by extending `ArrayAdapter` class for your spinner. Then add seperate layout for the  spinner. You can add it inside `getCustomView()` in your  CustomSpinnerAdapter . In that layout file add `TextView`  with the attribute `android:inputType="text"`.

Then in your activity you can add this adapter to you spinner by using `spinner.setAdapter(adapter)` method. Here adapter is the object of your CustomSpinnerAdapter class.

This is a tutorial to for [how to create a CustomSpinnerAdapter](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107).

**Note:** You have to customize this according to your requirement to get editable spinner.

Comment: I add a link for a tutorial. I think it will help you.

Comment: what i am looking for is different than the tutorial. e.i. i have in the spinner item 1 to item 8 . what i want to do is to allow the user from the setting page edit item 1 to be what ever he is looking for like instead of item 1 it will show XXXX